# Show twitter profile pic and total number of tweets(my/any user tweet count) in my Website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jsp, twitter

I'm want to show any twitter user profile pic and his/her tweet count in my application(JSP)
I searched and could find or didn't understand how to approach this, could someone throw me soem tips how and where to start, what i basically need is to show a twitter profile only picture of any user and his tweet count.

if i need to access Twitter profile pics what should i need ? how to start with ?
any tutorials ? basic tutorial to start access twitter api is much appreciated ?

What i tried is 
http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/05/10/how-to-check-for-new-tweets-from-a-user/

Comment: i'm sure the twitter api documents cover what you need to start, how to start, and how to access the tweets of user

Comment: twitter recently updated their api to v1.1 and you now require authentication to get such information. That tutorial will no longer work. Check their dev.twitter.com site for more

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.twitter.com/ ? The API is well documented. Also since june the API v1.0 is deprecated (and your tutorial uses the 1.0 API)

Comment: [User Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API 1 is now replaced by API 1.1 which requires OAuth, check https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline